# The Resource cannot be found . ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The resource cannot be found.

```
Requested URL: /Home/Home/Signup_User
```

However it should be `/Home/Signup_User`
where Home is the controller and `Signup_User` is the function in `Home Controller`.I have checked the spelling its correct.

My Sign Up Form as follows.

```
<form action="~/Home/Signup_User" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>
                Enter Name
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>
                Enter Age
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>
                Enter Email Address
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "large-12", placeholder = "xyz@gmail.com", type = "email" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>
                Enter Password
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { })
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <button type="submit" class="button tiny right" style="margin-left:5px;color:white;">Submit</button>
    <a href="#" class="button secondary tiny right close-reveal-modal" style="position:relative;    font-size: 0.6875rem;color:inherit;top:0;right:0;   font-weight: 300;" aria-label="Close">Cancel</a> }
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</form>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `~`?

Comment: Remove the leading `~`. The delete it and use `Html.BeginForm()` (or `action = "Url.Action(...)")` so that your urls are always generated correctly

Comment: are you using Areas

Comment: Why are you not using FormExtensions any reason behind that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using relative path in `action URL` . that's why `Home` Added twice like this.

```
/Home/Home/Signup_User
```

`Asp.net MVC` come up with beautiful `Form Extensions`.Just you need to specify `Controller Name,` `Action Method Name` and `Area name` if any.

for e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new {area = "AreaName"}))
```

In your case

```
ActionName :"Signup_User"
ControllerName:"Home"
```

Assuming, you don't have no area defined. replace your piece code with below snippet. it will resolve your issue.

**CODE:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Signup_User", "Home"))
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>
                    Enter Name
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>
                    Enter Age
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>
                    Enter Email Address
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "large-12", placeholder = "xyz@gmail.com", type = "email" })
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>
                    Enter Password
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { })
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="button tiny right" style="margin-left:5px;color:white;">Submit</button>
        <a href="#" class="button secondary tiny right close-reveal-modal" style="position:relative;    font-size: 0.6875rem;color:inherit;top:0;right:0;   font-weight: 300;" aria-label="Close">Cancel</a> }
        <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

FormExtensions (with Controller and ActionName)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Signup_User", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

FormExtensions (with Controller , ActionName and Area )

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Signup_User", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "AreaName" }))
{

}
```

[image: code snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 
action="~/Home/Signup_User"
 with 
action="@Url.Action("Signup_User", "Home")"

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add Controller name slash action name, no need to add ~

Refer following code for Solution 1:

```
<form action="/Home/Signup_User" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //Add rest of your code
</form>
```

Else, use MVC's built in HTML helper to render the form and put your rest of the code into same.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Signup_User", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  // Add your rest of code
}
```

Above code will generate empty  tag.

Answer (score 0):

One reason this could occur is if you don't have a start page set under your web project's properties. So do this:

Right click on your mvc project
Choose "Properties"
Select the "Web" tab
Select "Specific Page"
Assuming you have a controller called HomeController and an action method called Index, enter "home/index" in to the text box corresponding to the "Specific Page" radio button.

Now, if you launch your web application, it will take you to the view rendered by the HomeController's Index action method.